# Type inference and type bounds in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, type-bounds

Consider the following classes:

```
class Type { def +(other:Type):Type = this}
class SubType extends Type
```

Now I want to create a wrapper object which takes a binary function operating on `Type` or its derived types, let's start with:

```
case class Fct(f:(Type,Type) => Type)
```

I can instantiate the `Fct` class using the `_+_` apply method, but I cannot pass a function using the `Subtype` class, which is expected:

```
val f1 = Fct(_+_) // OK
val f2 = Fct((x:SubType,y:Type) => y) // error: found: (SubType, Type) => Type, required: (Type, Type) => Type
```

Now we can define `Fct` using generics and type bounds to accept the subtypes:

```
case class Fct[T <: Type, U <: Type, V <: Type](f:(T,U) => V)
```

Now `f2` is working as expected, but `f1` is not valid anymore, and I don't understand why:

```
val f1 = Fct(_+_)  // error: missing parameter type
val f2 = Fct((x:SubType,y:Type) => y) // OK
```

Is there a syntax which would accept both `f1` and `f2`?

**Edit**

*(reply to m-z)* Is there a way to get around the variance issues with a factory? Something like:

```
class Fct(f:(Type,Type) => Type)
object Fct {
  def apply(f:(Type,Type) => Type): Fct = new Fct(f)
  def apply[T <: Type, U <: Type, V <: Type](f:(T,U) => V): Fct =
    new Fct((x:Type,y:Type) => {(x,y) match {
      case (a:T, b:U) => f(a,b)
      case _ => ???
    }}: Type)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `Fct((x: SubType, y: Type) => y)` is not syntax, it's variance. `f` in `Fct` has type `(Type, Type) => Type`, i.e. `Function2[Type, Type, Type]`. `Function2` is contravariant over its first two type parameters.

This means that `(SubType, Type) => Type` *is not* a sub-type of `(Type, Type) => Type`. Therefore you cannot use it in place of `(Type, Type) => Type`. Note that `Fct((x: Type, y: Type) => y)` works just fine.

With the generic version of `Fct`, when you write `Fct(_+_)`, there is no way to infer the types `T` and `U`. The best you can hope for in that case is something like:

```
Fct[SubType, Type, Type](_ + _)
```

In short, the first approach will work fine, but your function parameter types are nailed down to `Type` (or super types of that, which you probably do not want). That may be okay though, because you can still pass `SubType` as parameters to that function, you just cannot restrict the parameters to `SubType` without breaking the contravariance of `Function2`. The second approach will only work if you annotate the types *somewhere*.

Comment: I was hoping to get around the variance issue using a factory pattern. I added one of my tries to the question, but the syntax is still not correct.

Comment: @Thibaut You might be able to get that to compile, but you'll be lying to the compiler. `Fct` will think it holds a `(Type, Type) => Type`, when it doesn't. Which means if you pass a `Type` as one of the parameters, but it is actually a sub-type, you'll get a `ClassCastException` exception at runtime.

Comment: That would be fine. The downcasts would obviously be less crude than in my example and I can implement the correct error checks. The problem is convincing the typesystem to let me do it.

Comment: @Thibaut It would be what you want, but not fine. Imho, it's high way to hell.

Comment: I am not sure why you consider this an antipattern. In terms of casting issues and exceptions, it does not cause more problems than a partial function: `val f: PartialFunction[(Type,Type),Type] = {case (x:SubType, y:Type) => y}`. I want my `Fct` to behave in a similar way, but default to `(Type,Type) => Type` if no type is provided.

Comment: A clarification for your answer, I do not expect `_+_` to be `(SubType, Type) => Type` but `(Type, Type) => Type`, since there in no context to infer the types from.